# Format column in a template using rowdatabound

Tags: gridview, rowdatabound

I have a gridview and i have a column that shows order number. That column is in `ItemTemplate` with different `CommandArgument` and text. The number has to be displayed in a particular format and i have a function that returns the number in that format. I need to access the column values in `RowDataBound` event. Like `e.rows.cells(0).text = function_name(e.rows.cells(0).text)`.

But my question is how to access the values inside the `ItemTemplate`. And I do not want to wrap the values inside a control.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ItemTemplate mean it is the regular value in GridView without being edited etc. You can access it using

GridView.FindControl('..')

Comment: OK. But how do i change the format of the same column. Without template i just do e.rows.cells(0).text = function_name(e.rows.cells(0).text) and it works. How to do the same thing with Findcontrol?